# SAS - What is a good way to check if any of the variables in a list is missing

Tags: sas

I have datasets where I sometimes need to select observations where none of the variables in the list are missing.

i.e I have to do this.

```
Where E1 NE . and E2 NE . and E3 NE .
```

or I can do it little bit more easily like this:

```
Where E1+E2+E3 NE .
```

**But is there any way in SAS to do something like:**

```
Where not missing(E1 - E3)
```

---

It doesn't work if I do

```
where sum(of E1-E3) NE .
```

Because that is equivalent to

```
Where E1 NE . or E2 NE . or E3 NE .
```

But  i need "and" instead of "or".

---

I could also loop over  those variables in a dataset and build a variable for the selection like:

```
array E E1-E3;
misind = 0;
do i=1 to dim(E);
    if E(i) = . then misind = 1;
end;
```

But that's not so simple either!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you may use function `nmiss` or `cmiss` to check the exact number of columns with missing values.

for numerical columns. No column in e1-e3 is missing.

```
if nmiss(of e1-e3) = 0
```

for numerical/char mixed columns. No column in e1-e3 is missing.

```
if cmiss(of e1-e3) = 0
```

Comment: This is how I'd do it as well.

Comment: The nmiss or cmiss functions don't work in Where clause for me. I can only use them in data step like x=nmiss(of e1-e3). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Pekka sorry, my mistake. Here you must use `if`.

Comment: Okay. It's still a good solution and just the kind of one liner I was looking for. Still, I wonder why SAS can't make it work in "where" when it could be used in all the procedures. For example I need this in Proc Means all the time.